# Get time according to rfc3339 with offset

Tags: c++, formatting

I need to get time according to rfc3339 with time zone offset.
Currently I have:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto t = std::time(nullptr);
    auto tm = *std::localtime(&t);

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::put_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S%z");
    std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But the results has one minor issue, the time is:
2019-01-10T10-19-31+0100
But it should be:
2019-01-10T10-19-31+01:00
I checked the documentation:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time
and there seems to not be a way to specify the colon in time offset.
Is there a way to do it with c++11 std::put_time or with something else c++ stl provides

Comment: Since you already have the date/time in a `std:string` (because of your use of `std::ostringstream`) then you could quite easily check if the third-to-last character is a colon `':'` or not, and if not then insert it.

Comment: Yes that is possible but I was thinking if there is a solution that does not need postprocessing on the output